# Create jquery dropdown like RDP Menu Bar

Tags: jquery, menu, hidden, rdp

I'm not all that familiar with jquery so I'm not quite sure how to do this.  Basically, I want a block of html to stay hidden at the top of the page with a ~3px edge sticking out (something to mouseover), and when you mouse over it, the hidden section slides down.

Basically I want it to work like the RDP full screen menu bar works.  Any thoughts on what the best way of doing this is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jquery:

```
$("#slide").bind("mouseover", function() {
     $(this).animate({
          top: '+=189'                      
     });
}).bind("mouseout", function() {
     $(this).animate({
          top: '-=189'                      
     });
});
```

style:

```
   <style type="text/css">
   #slide {
     background:#ccc;
     border:1px solid #000;
     width:200px;
     height:200px;
     padding:10px;
     position:absolute;
     top:-190px;
     }
  </style>
```

html:

```
<div id="slide">
test<br>
test<br>
test<br>
test
</div>
```

Comment: This looks great.  One problem though, it doesn't stay down on mouseover.  It bounces up and down.  Check out communityftw.com top right.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it with the help of Jquery UI

http://jqueryui.com/demos/hide/
Pick slide in the dropdown menu.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses.  With a little tweaking of the above code I found out above the .hover() method.  The above javascript would then look like

```
$("#slide").hover(function () {
            $(this).animate({
                top: '+=30'
            });
        }, function () {
            $(this).animate({
                top: '-=30'
            });
        });
```